# OpenERP - Report Creation

Tags: python, report, openoffice.org, odoo, openoffice-writer

I am trying to create a new report with report plugin and openoffice but I don't know how to assign it in the OpenERP system.

Is there someone who can give me exact steps for creation of new report and integration with openerp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's always a good idea to describe what you've tried so far, what documentation you've found, and so on. That way answers won't repeat stuff you already know, and we can get a clearer idea of what the problem is.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps to create the OpenERP RML report.

1. open open-office.org

   - tools menu

     - extension manager

       - go to - base_report_designer
       - plugin  →openerp_report_designer.zip
2. - restart open-office
3. - open a new report
   - add a loop ( select your DB)
   - add loop as a repeat
   - add a field  and make it customize look
   - save file as a .sxw  or send to the server
4. convert .sxw to .rml

   - `$> cd to base-report-designer/openerp_sxw2rml`
   - `$> python openerp_sxw2rml.py ../../exam/report/.sxw > ../../exam/report/.rml`
5. (in report folder)

   - exam.py  (or copy it from http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_1_openoffice_report.html):

     ```
     import time 
     from report import report_sxw 
     class exam(report_sxw.rml_parse): 
          def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context): 
                 super(exam, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context) 
                 self.localcontext.update({ 
                  'time': time, 
                 }) 
     report_sxw.report_sxw('report.exam.student', 'exam.student', 
             'addons/exam/report/exam.rml', parser=exam, header=True)
     ```
   - (exam.py, exam.rml, exam.sxw, __init__.py)
   - __init__.py:

     ```
     import exam
     ```
6. (main exam folder)

   - exam_report.xml

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0"?> 
     <openerp> 
         <data> 
             <report 
                     id="exam_student" 
                     string="Print Exam..." 
                     model="exam.student" 
                     name="exam.student" 
                     rml="exam/report/exam.rml" 
                     auto="False" 
                     header="False"/> 
         </data> 
     </openerp>
     ```
   - __openerp__.py
          in update  → 'exam_report.xml'
   - __init__.py

     ```
     import report
     ```

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for creating a new report and adding it to OpenERP are in the [developer documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_1_openoffice_report.html). It sounds like you might be asking specifically about how to make the report appear in the user interface. That is described in the [section on server PDF output](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_1_openoffice_report.html#server-pdf-output).

Answer (score 1):

First you save .odt file then connect with server and select open new report and then send it ti server with proper report name and then keep on editing your report by selecting the option modify existing report.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohtFjjg8FCc

This will help you.

Comment: Some details about what the video says would be useful, esp if the vid gets pulled in the future (and for people like myself where youtube is blocked at work)